# Removing spaces from part of the pattern

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a tab separated file that is in the following format:

```
MY, 12    MOM, 56    {INT-SAM}BARS ABCD;{INT-SAM}CHEC ABC TH    [SAMPLE CODE] BOLE IRTH.    SAMPLE 678    1213y12415
ZINC, 34,    ABC,78    {INT-SAM}CAST IRTH;{INT-SAM}ZXYZ DEFG TH    [SAMPLE CODE] BEEB ABCD EFGH.    SAMPLE 901    101 9y8 1617
M 12    M 56    {INT-SAM}BARS ABCD;{INT-SAM}CHEC IR TH;{INT-NUM}132435    [SAMPLE CODE] BOLE XYZR.    SAMPLE LOTS    WINTER
```

I need to use VBScript regular expressions to remove spaces in the text between:

1. `{INT-SAM}` and `;` or `\t`
2. `[SAMPLE CODE]` and a period (`\.`)

Also, I need to make sure that I'm removing spaces only from the 3rd and 4th column. If these patterns appear anywhere else, they should be left as is.

I've got till here:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objRegEx : Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

Dim OriginalWCFile : OriginalFile = "test.csv"
Dim PatchedWCFile : PatchedFile = "patch.csv"

Dim objFile, objOutFile, strSearchString, Line, strNewLine
Dim strReplaceString, ptrn, StringPattern, strWriteLine, strWriteLine2
Dim strStringToBeReplaced, strStringTest

Call ReplaceP

Sub ReplaceP
    Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(OriginalFile)
    Set objOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile(PatchedFile, True)

    Do While objFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
        Line = objFile.ReadLine
        objOutFile.Write(Line & vbCrlf)
        strWriteLine = RegexRemoveSpaces(Line, "(([\S ]+\t){2})((\{INT-SAM\}[0-9A-Z ]+[;|\t])+)(([\S ]+\t){3})")
        objOutFile.Write(strWriteLine & vbCrlf)
        strWriteLine = RegexRemoveSpaces(strWriteLine, "(([\S ]+\t){3})((\[SAMPLE CODE\][0-9A-Z ;]+\.))(([\S ]+\t){2})")
        objOutFile.Write(strWriteLine & vbCrlf)
    Loop
    objFile.Close
    objOutFile.Close
End Sub

Function RegexRemoveSpaces(strString, strPattern)
    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.Pattern = strPattern
    strStringTest = strString

    If objRegEx.Test(strStringTest) Then
        Set StringPattern = objRegEx.Execute(strStringTest)
        WScript.echo StringPattern.Count
        For Each ptrn In StringPattern
            WScript.Echo ptrn.value
            strStringToBeReplaced = objRegEx.Replace(ptrn.value, "$2") 'Doesn't Work
            WScript.Echo strStringToBeReplaced
            strReplaceString = Replace(strStringToBeReplaced, " ", "")
            strNewLine = objRegEx.Replace(strString, "$1" & strReplaceString & "$3" )
        Next
        If InStr(strNewLine,"[SAMPLECODE]") > 0 Then
            strNewLine = Replace(strNewLine, "[SAMPLECODE]", "[SAMPLE CODE]")
        End If
        RegexRemoveSpaces = strNewLine
    Else
        RegexRemoveSpaces = strString
    End If
End Function
```

When I run the above code, the below line seems to be giving me unreliable answers:

```
strStringToBeReplaced = objRegEx.Replace(ptrn.value, "$2")
```

For the first line, please see below outputs when I use different pattern numbers:

"$1" - `MY, 12    MOM, 56`    - this is what I was expecting.

"$2" - `MOM, 56`    - When the above is $1, why is this `$2`?

"$3" - `{INT-SAM}BARS ABCD;{INT-SAM}CHEC ABC TH`    - this is what I hoped would be `$2`.

I'm not sure if I've over-complicated the solution. I think I'm using the nesting of `()` wrong but I can't figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to work with a [replacement function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx#scripting12_topic4) here. Something like this:

```
filename = "C:\path\to\input.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
txt = Split(fso.OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll, vbNewLine)

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\{INT-SAM\}(.*?)[;\t]|\[SAMPLE CODE\](.*?)\."
re.Global  = True

Function cleanup(m, s1, s2, pos, src)
    If Not IsEmpty(s1) Then
        s = s1
    Else
        s = s2
    End If
    cleanup = Replace(m, s, Replace(s, " ", ""))
End Function

For Each line In txt
    WScript.Echo re.Replace(line, GetRef("cleanup"))
Next
```